# List Errors After Update SharePoint 2013 (15.0.4569.1506)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, update

We did maintenance on our SharePoint server which included 40 updates (6 product updates and 34 security updates) to our SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013.  Now when the users go to any list on any browser (Chrome, FireFox, IE) instead of the list displaying, they get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of null
```

If they browse with a mobile device, it displays fine.

Answer (score 2):

Several people ran into the issue that list views stop working after installing [MS16-004.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms16-004)

The security fix contains a code change which requires as well an update to the not localized and to the localized files of the SharePoint foundation component. Localized and not localized file are installed through two different msp files and the security fix package does not include the localized msp file.

If you are looking for a minimal change to resolve the issue it you can just install the following fix which contains the missing msp file containing the localized files:

[KB 3114508](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114508) – Download location: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50667

Alternatively you can install the full server package of [January 2016 CU for SharePoint 201](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/01/12/january-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)3 which also includes the required msp file.

Source: [Solution for the list view issue with MS16-004 (January 2016 PU) for SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/01/15/solution-for-the-list-view-issue-with-ms16-004-january-2016-pu-for-sharepoint-2013/)